# Quickblox Simple iOS Push Badge Increment

Tags: apple-push-notifications, badge, quickblox

Hi I'm using quickblox in one of my iOS apps and so far everything has been great and easy to use, however, I've seem to have hit a wall. I'm trying to increment my applications badge count for when I receive new push notifications from quickblox but I can't seem to figure out how I should pass the count from simple push in the iOS simple push api.

I also would like to pass a variable to tell my app where to open to once a push notification is received any help with how I can do this using quickblox would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hey have you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this code sample to manage badge counter and other values

```
NSString *mesage = @"This is push";

NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
[aps setObject:mesage forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
[aps setObject:@"5" forKey:QBMPushMessageBadgeKey];
[payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

QBMPushMessage *message = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];

[QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:@"45288,300" delegate:self];
```

Comment: That wouldn't send from iOS to Android users though would it? We're on both os's

Comment: Android push notifications don't have badge counter value

Comment: @IgorKhomenko in iOS badge count is not increasing when app is in background why so ? does quickblox tracking badge count ?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, I think there's some mess. I'm getting badge count updated when app received push from QuickBlox server (not sent via code).. but how do I manage the badge when a push would get send by me (via code). How do I know, there are 6 badge value (from server) and one is from my side so I've to pass 7 for that particular user.

Comment: does QuickBlox increment badge count automatically. Seems it sends just badge count = 1 each time for new payload even if you send 10 messages.